# modify provisioning profile from xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, organizer

i have multiple provisionnig profile and in this times i have to add( and delete) devices, and this make me crazy, in fact i go to developer.apple.com and remove or add devices for those profiles, and i have to download it,add it to organizer ans delete the old ones otherwise i cant manage all of theme.

i look to xcode(4.3.2) and i see that i can add provisioning profile.

there is a way to MODIFY existing one ?

or can you tell me how you do in this cases ?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the standard developer.apple.com is the only way. Apple adds a digital signature to the provisioning profile, so any modification made by anyone else invalidates it.

Comment: ok thank you, but i think it will be really helpful to add it to xcode.

Comment: I agree. I wish getting an app on a phone would not involve so many manual steps.